# "TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment"; iteration issue

Tags: python

```
def create_board():
    b = [[['',''] for i in range(8)] for j in range(8)]
    return b
game_board = create_board()


for i in game_board[0]:
    for idx, val in enumerate(i[1::2]):
        idx[0] = 0
        idx[1] = 0
print game_board
```

I have the this script, in which I need to iterate through the first list that is within the list game_board. Starting at the second element I need to change the values in every other element's list. However when I run this I am greeted with the error

```
idx[0] = 0
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

It would be understandable if IDLE was complaining about me assigning a  variable to a str, (which would be an issue with iterating over values rather than indices), but i can't see why this problem is happening considering I have no integers.

Comment: `enumerate()` pairs each item in your sequence with its index: `(index, item)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

idx is just an integer like `0` and there is no such thing a `0[0]`

you want to use val which is your item from your list.

actually it looks like you have other problems ...

**fixed**

```
for row in game_board:
    for item in row:
        item[0] = 0
        item[1] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The enumerate() function returns a tuple that is (integer, object) -- see [the python documenation for enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

You are trying to index an integer, which you can't.